# How to query and retrieve a list of field-value pairs from X509 certificate in Java?

Tags: java, x509certificate, bouncycastle, jce

In your browser if you go to Advanced Settings and then view the certificates, and select one and click on View (at least on Windows), you will see a popup dialog with 3 tabs. The Details tab will show a tabular list of Field and Value. Are these constant, or will they change?

Since they are just rows in a table, it is logical that they will vary.
If they vary (are dynamic), then is there any way to query and retrieve a list of these name-value pairs to avoid hard-coding X509Certificate.getX(), getY(), getZ()...?

**UPDATE:**
From Windows Help (copied below), it appears that some fields are fixed, and others are extensions.

> Details Tab The Details tab provides the following information about
>   the certificate:
>
> Version. The X.509 version number.
>
> Serial number. The unique serial number that the issuing certification
>   authority (CA) assigns to the certificate. The serial number is unique
>   for all certificates issued by a given CA.
>
> Signature algorithm. The hash algorithm that the CA uses to digitally
>   sign the certificate.
>
> Issuer. Information regarding the CA that issued the certificate.
>
> Valid from. The beginning date for the period in which the certificate
>   is valid.
>
> Valid to. The final date for the period in which the certificate is
>   valid.
>
> Subject. The name of the individual, computer, device, or CA to whom
>   the certificate is issued. If the issuing CA exists on a domain member
>   server in your enterprise, this will be a distinguished name within
>   the enterprise. Otherwise, this may be a full name and e-mail name or
>   other personal identifier.
>
> Public key. The public key type and length associated with the
>   certificate.
>
> Thumbprint algorithm. The hash algorithm that generates a digest of
>   data (or thumbprint) for digital signatures.
>
> Thumbprint. The digest (or thumbprint) of the certificate data.
>
> Friendly name. (Optional) A display name to use instead of the name in
>   the Subject field.
>
> Enhanced key usage. (Optional) The purposes for which this certificate
>   can be used.
>
> There are additional X.509 v3 extensions that can be used in a
>   certificate. If they are present, they will be displayed.

Comment: The [`X509Certificate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/X509Certificate.html) class should have methods to access all of those values.

Comment: @VGR In other words, the list of fields is constant for all X509 certs? The fact that it is displayed as rows in a table indicates otherwise.

Comment: @VGR If the list of fields vary, then I was hoping to avoid hardcoding getX(), getY(), getZ()...

Comment: Yes, the fields are constant.  See the documentation for the X509Certificate class (to which I've linked), and also the [RFC 3280 standard](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3280) to which that class documentation links.